# MySQL how can I achieve this query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

**I have the following Mock table:**

```
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| NAME    | TITLE             | SIZE |  Hit |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| A       | Hippo1            | H    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo2            | H    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo3            | H    |  1   |   
| A       | Hippo1            | M    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo2            | M    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo3            | M    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo1            | L    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo2            | L    |  1   |    
| A       | Hippo3            | L    |  1   |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| B       | Snail1            | H    |  1   |
| B       | Snail1            | M    |  0   |
| B       | Snail1            | L    |  1   |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| C       | Dog               | H    |  1   |
| C       | Dog               | M    |  0   |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| D       | Sheep             | H    |  0   |
| D       | Sheep             | L    |  1   |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| E       | Fish              | H    |  1   |
| E       | Fish              | H    |  1   |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
```

**My Desired Result would**

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| NAME    | TITLE    | SCORE |
+---------+----------+-------+
| A       | Hippo    |  100  |
| B       | Snail    |   80  |
| C       | Dog      |   80  |
| D       | Sheep    |   10  |
| E       | Fish     |  100  |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

**Computations required:**

- Type can have only three values at most: {H, M, L};
- When all values are present, they are graded as followed: H=70 M=20 L=10
- ALL unique casese are

  1. Case {H,M} : H=80 M=20
  2. Case {M,L} : M=60 L=40
  3. Case {H,L} : H=90 L=10
  4. Case {H} : H=100
  5. Case {M} : M=100
  6. Case {L} : L=100
  7. Case {H,M,L} : H=70 M=20 L=10

**Explanation:**

```
Hippo Has case {H,M,L}
Snail has case {H,M,L}
Dog has case {H,M}
Sheep has case {H,L}
Fish has case {H}
```

**Further Explanation**

Hippo : Athough not all sizes have a hit, Hippo has gained the score 100 because atleast 1 of each case has been satified once per title. Hence **HIPPO3** has all three `H` `M`
`L` satsified so **hippo** can be conidered found 100 percent

**Extracted from above (lines are logical construct for viewer)**

```
| A       | Hippo1            | H    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo2            | H    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo3            | H    |  1   | <--Here   
+-------------------------------------------+    
| A       | Hippo1            | M    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo2            | M    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo3            | M    |  1   | <--Here
+-------------------------------------------+   
| A       | Hippo1            | L    |  0   |
| A       | Hippo2            | L    |  1   |    
| A       | Hippo3            | L    |  1   | <--Here
```

Comment: Unless you actually have a zoo ;) is this homework?

Comment: It's ok if it is, and we will help, it just needs to be tagged that way if so.

Comment: No I assure you this is not homework

Comment: Is there always at most one digit after the title?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I can't say I've ever seen a zoo that has cases of hippos ;)

Comment: @MichaelMior its a statistical problem on types of animals

Comment: @stackoverflow shouldn't Dog have an 80 there?

Comment: @MostyMostacho good catch that was a typo Thanks greatly

Comment: @stackoverflow: How do you transform `Hippo1, Hippo2, Hippo3` into `Hippo`? I think that field shouldn't be in the result set

Comment: @MostyMostacho I can add the other table that it references but I dont wish to confuse my reader and make this ambiguous. You can treat the above table as standalone. But there is another table called `Farm` that holds the animals (IE. Hippo, Bird etc). To get all Hippos, Birds, etc (the table had to be normalized) we reference `Gate` to get all animal from that ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select name, sum(FinalVal) Score from (
  select distinct t.name,
    case
      when size = 'H' then Hval
      when size = 'M' then Mval
      else Lval
    end FinalVal
  from (
    select name,
      case
        when sizes = 'H,L,M' then 70
        when sizes = 'H,M' then 80
        when sizes = 'H,L' then 90
        when sizes = 'H' then 100
        else 0
      end Hval,
      case
        when sizes = 'H,L,M' then 20
        when sizes = 'H,M' then 20
        when sizes = 'L,M' then 60
        when sizes = 'M' then 100
        else 0
      end Mval,
      case
        when sizes = 'H,L,M' then 10
        when sizes = 'L,M' then 40
        when sizes = 'H,L' then 10
        when sizes = 'L' then 100
        else 0
      end Lval
    from (
      select name, group_concat(distinct size order by size) sizes from t
      group by name
    ) s1
  ) s2
  join t on t.name = s2.name
  where hit
) final
group by name
```

It is not clear how to get the Title given your data (actually the result has data it is not present in the original tables, such as `Hippo`, instead of `Hippo1`. But I'll leave that to you.

This will result in:

```
+------+-------+
| NAME | SCORE |
+------+-------+
| A    |   100 |
| B    |    80 |
| C    |    80 |
| D    |    10 |
| E    |   100 |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: I have no Idea whats goin on there but I tried with what you supplied above with no luck

Comment: I tried to modify fiddle for you to view but the changes didnt stay persistent. Does fiddle only allow the creator to modify?

Comment: When you modify it the URL changes and you have to share that new link. The original will remain the same

Comment: please review the revision above if you will. Thanks Mosty Mostacho

Comment: Any Suggestions? I tried fabricating the answer you had supplied but couldnt pull it together

Comment: Sorry, @stackoverflow, the previous question was already quite complex (70 times viewed only 1 answer), and this is a different one. It means doing it from scratch, what would make my previous effort useless. What I think you should have done is mark it as accepted (because the answer was accurate), and create a new one with the real tables. I can't work on this right now, but I'll check your profile later and see any additional question you post and try to provide an answer, if needed. But please, make sure you don't change the requirements of the other question. Thanks

Comment: Here is the new http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830062/mysql-how-do-i-create-this-subquery and here is the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be72/3 Please have a look and Thank you greatly Mosty Mostacho!