# MySQL How do I create this subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

**I have the following tables**

Table Farm

```
+---------+--------+-------------------+-----------+------------+
| FARM_ID |Stock_ID| FARM_TITLE        | Size      | FARM_VALUE |
+---------+--------+-------------------+-----------+------------+
|       2 |      1 | AgriZone          | M         |        202 |
|       3 |      1 | Cow Mill          | L         |         11 |
|       4 |      2 | Beef Farm         | H         |        540 |
|       5 |      2 | CattleOne         | M         |       1080 |
|       6 |      2 | FarmOne           | L         |        455 |
|       7 |      3 | Perdue            | H         |        333 |
|       8 |      4 | Holstein          | M         |        825 |
|      10 |      1 | Dotterers         | H         |         98 |
+---------+--------+-------------------+-----------+------------+
```

Table Gate

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| GATE_ID | FARM_ID | FARM_VALUE |
+---------+---------+------------+
|       1 |       2 |          0 |
|       1 |       3 |          0 |
|       1 |       4 |        540 |
|       2 |       4 |        550 |
|       3 |       4 |        560 |
|       4 |       4 |        570 |
|       5 |       4 |        580 |
|       6 |       4 |        590 |
|       1 |       5 |       1080 |
|       2 |       5 |       1100 |
|       3 |       5 |       1120 |
|       4 |       5 |       1140 |
|       5 |       5 |       1160 |
|       6 |       5 |       1180 |
|       1 |       6 |        455 |
|       2 |       6 |        536 |
|       3 |       6 |        617 |
|       4 |       6 |        698 |
|       5 |       6 |        779 |
|       6 |       6 |        860 |
|       1 |       7 |          0 |
|       1 |       8 |          0 |
|       1 |      10 |          0 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

Table Origin

```
+--------+----------+
| ORI_ID | ORI_NAME |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |   US     |
|      2 |   CA     |
|      3 |   MX     |
+--------+----------+
```

Table Stock

```
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|Stock_ID| ORI_ID | Stock_TITLE       |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
|      1 |      1 | P1                |
|      2 |      2 | P3                |
|      3 |      3 | Q4                |
|      4 |      3 | B3                |
+--------+--------+-------------------+
```

Table Results

```
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| RESULT_ID | FARM_ID | GATE_ID | FARM_VALUE |    Score%  |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|         1 |       7 |       1 |        333 |        100 |
|         2 |       8 |       1 |        825 |        100 |
|         3 |       6 |       1 |        455 |         40 |
|         4 |       6 |       2 |        536 |          0 |
|         5 |       6 |       3 |        617 |          0 |
|         6 |       6 |       4 |        698 |        100 |
|         7 |       6 |       5 |        779 |          0 |
|         8 |       6 |       6 |        860 |         10 |
|         9 |       4 |       1 |        540 |        100 |
|        10 |       4 |       2 |        550 |         90 |
|        11 |       4 |       3 |        560 |          0 |
|        12 |       4 |       4 |        570 |        100 |
|        13 |       4 |       5 |        580 |         10 |
|        14 |       4 |       6 |        590 |          0 |
|        15 |       5 |       1 |       1080 |          0 |
|        16 |       5 |       2 |       1100 |          0 |
|        17 |       5 |       3 |       1120 |          0 |
|        18 |       5 |       4 |       1140 |         50 |
|        19 |       5 |       5 |       1160 |          0 |
|        20 |       5 |       6 |       1180 |        100 |
|        21 |       3 |       1 |         11 |        100 |
|        22 |      10 |       1 |         98 |         90 |
|        23 |       2 |       1 |        202 |        100 |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

**Annotated Result table: Same as above  ^**

```
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| RESULT_ID | FARM_ID | GATE_ID | FARM_VALUE |   Score%   |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+

+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|         1 |       7 |       1 |        333 |        100 | <--|H-Case {H}
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+    

+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+     
|         2 |       8 |       1 |        825 |        100 | <--|M-Case {M}
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+

+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|         3 |       6 |       1 |        455 |         40 |
|         4 |       6 |       2 |        536 |          0 |
|         5 |       6 |       3 |        617 |          0 |
|         6 |       6 |       4 |        698 |        100 |  <--|L
|         7 |       6 |       5 |        779 |          0 |     |
|         8 |       6 |       6 |        860 |         10 |     |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+     |
|         9 |       4 |       1 |        540 |        100 |     |
|        10 |       4 |       2 |        550 |         90 |     |
|        11 |       4 |       3 |        560 |          0 |     |
|        12 |       4 |       4 |        570 |        100 |  <--+M-case {H,M,L}
|        13 |       4 |       5 |        580 |         10 |     |
|        14 |       4 |       6 |        590 |          0 |     |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+     |
|        15 |       5 |       1 |       1080 |          0 |     |
|        16 |       5 |       2 |       1100 |          0 |     |
|        17 |       5 |       3 |       1120 |          0 |     |
|        18 |       5 |       4 |       1140 |         50 |  <--|H
|        19 |       5 |       5 |       1160 |          0 |
|        20 |       5 |       6 |       1180 |        100 |
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+

+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|        21 |       3 |       1 |         11 |        100 | <--|L
|        22 |      10 |       1 |         98 |         90 | <--+H-case {H,M,L}
|        23 |       2 |       1 |        202 |        100 | <--|M
+-----------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

**Computations required:**

- Type can have only three values at most: {H, M, L};
- When all values are present, they are graded as followed: H=70 M=20 L=10
- ALL unique casese are
- Case {H,M}   : H=80 M=20
- Case {M,L}   : M=60 L=40
- Case {H,L}   : H=90 L=10
- Case {H}     : H=100
- Case {M}     : M=100
- Case {L}     : L=100
- Case {H,M,L} : H=70 M=20 L=10

**Further Explanation**

- **Only** Stock with with **atleast one** `GATE`, fully satisfied can get 100 points max

  1. Example: `Q4` has 3 sets of 6 `GATES`; Only one `GATE` set has to be satsified (have a score present).
  2. The points present must be Multiplied against the particular case it pertains Example: `Q4` has case {H,M,L} which means H=70; M=20; L=10 This would results in (70*100%)+(20*50%)+(10*100%)=90 **(look back above at the Result table annotations)**
    2.
- Points should still be considered and accounted for even when a gate hasn't been fully satisfied. The gate with MAX points earned should be kept when no gates have been fully satisfied. (Will provide further explanation if not understood)

**If we Perform a query to make sense of the tables and data it will look like below**

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| Origin  | Stock     | Farm Title    | Farm Value|   Gate  |  Size     |  Score  |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
| US      | P1        | Perdue        |       333 |       1 | H         |     100 |
| US      | P3        | Holstein      |       825 |       1 | M         |     100 |
| CA      | Q4        | FarmOne       |       455 |       1 | L         |      40 |
| CA      | Q4        | FarmOne       |       536 |       2 | L         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | FarmOne       |       617 |       3 | L         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | FarmOne       |       698 |       4 | L         |     100 |
| CA      | Q4        | FarmOne       |       779 |       5 | L         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | FarmOne       |       860 |       6 | L         |      10 |
| CA      | Q4        | Beef Farm     |       540 |       1 | H         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | Beef Farm     |       550 |       2 | H         |      90 |
| CA      | Q4        | Beef Farm     |       560 |       3 | H         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | Beef Farm     |       570 |       4 | H         |     100 |
| CA      | Q4        | Beef Farm     |       580 |       5 | H         |      10 |
| CA      | Q4        | Beef Farm     |       590 |       6 | H         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | CattleOne     |      1080 |       1 | M         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | CattleOne     |      1100 |       2 | M         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | CattleOne     |      1120 |       3 | M         |       0 |
| CA      | Q4        | CattleOne     |      1140 |       4 | M         |      50 |
| CA      | Q4        | CattleOne     |      1160 |       5 | M         |     100 |
| CA      | Q4        | CattleOne     |      1180 |       6 | M         |       0 |
| MX      | B3        | Cow Mill      |        11 |       1 | L         |     100 |
| MX      | B3        | Dotterers     |        98 |       1 | H         |      90 |
| MX      | B3        | AgriZone      |       202 |       1 | M         |     100 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

**Desire Results**

```
+---------+-------------------+-------+
| Origin  |  Stock            | score |
+---------+-------------------+-------+
| US      |   P1              |   100 |
| US      |   P3              |   100 |
| CA      |   Q4              |    90 |
| MX      |   B3              |    93 |
+---------+-------------------+-------+
```

[image: Explanation]

Since `origin` has a `stock` which consists of 3 different `farms` and those `farms` have 6 `gates` each. As long as one `gate`-set (numerically matching `gates`) is scored to SOME value we can consider the entire `STOCK` found completely. This is the only way a `stock` can be considered 100.

Moreover and to reiterate, `STOCK` Q4 has case: {H,M,L} and all of `gate (4)` was found to some degree. `gate` 4 has the score (100% * H) + (50% * M) + (100% * L) which equals (70*100%) + (20*50%) + (10*100%) = 90

Hence: (Taken from above)

```
  | CA      |   Q4              |    90 |
```

**QED**

**So what I need help with** is creating the subquery/subselect to do make this computation work. I set up everything in the scenario above (along with a query in progress that I've been working with) in the SQL fiddle link below.

Thanks greatly stackoverflow community.

[**> The above problem in SqlFiddle can be found here <**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be72/3)

Comment: what are you having trouble with?  why did you indicate subquery?

Comment: Looks like homework.

Comment: @Randy It will be some type of subquery off of Results table because all the information will need to be drawn from there. Only origin name and stock title will need to used for presentation in desired result

Comment: @Crontab Dont be confused that a thoroughly explained problem has to come from a classroom.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Yeah the Results table is an actual table. All values can be directly referenced from that table and joined amongst the other tables.

Comment: @MostyMostacho if you look at `Stock Q4` then look at each of its 'farms' you will see each `Farm` represents a case `H`, `M`, and `L`. Thus we get the case `{H,M,L}`. Each `gate` under a 'Farm' carries the same `size`. So for example `CattleOne` is of `size` `M` and every `gate` under that is also of `size` `M`. So back to your question; since M=20 points for reason of `Stock Q4` having all `{HML}`. we then look to our `M` value present which holds the score of 50%. We multiply `M`(20) by %50 which equals 10.

Comment: I hope that helped. I know the requirements are bit ambiguous

Comment: The result I get given the data in your fiddle is the following: `(US, P1, 93), (CA, P3, 90), (MX, Q4, 100), (MX, B3, 100)`. Please, let me know if there is an error matching your fiddle data against your question data.

Comment: @MostyMostacho `US` `P1` should have 100 because there is only case `{H}` and score is 100 therefore 100% * 100  = 100. `US` `P2` should have 100 because there is only case `{M}` which means M=100 and `M` has the score of 100 in this case. therefore 100&*100=100, `MX` `B3` has the case `{HML}` therefore H=70, M=20=, L=20. H has the score 90 so (90%*70) + (100%*20) + (100%*10) = 93.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the query I've been working on. However, the results are slighly different from the ones you've posted in your question:

```
select o.origin_name, s.stock_title, sum(
  case f.size
    when 'H' then
      case
        when sizes = 'H,L,M' then 70
        when sizes = 'H,M' then 80
        when sizes = 'H,L' then 90
        when sizes = 'H' then 100
        else 0
      end
    when 'M' then
      case
        when sizes = 'H,L,M' then 20
        when sizes = 'H,M' then 20
        when sizes = 'L,M' then 60
        when sizes = 'M' then 100
        else 0
      end
    else
      case
        when sizes = 'H,L,M' then 10
        when sizes = 'L,M' then 40
        when sizes = 'H,L' then 10
        when sizes = 'L' then 100
        else 0
      end
  end * r.score / 100) FinalScore
from farm f
join (
  select f.stock_id, group_concat(distinct f.size order by f.size) sizes
  from farm f
  join results r on f.farm_id = r.farm_id
  group by f.stock_id
) stockSizes on f.stock_id = stockSizes.stock_id
join results r on f.farm_id = r.farm_id
join (
  select f.stock_id, r.gate_id
  from results r
  join farm f on r.farm_id = f.farm_id
  group by f.stock_id, r.gate_id
  having sum(r.score = 0) = 0
) FullGates
on FullGates.stock_id = f.stock_id and FullGates.gate_id = r.gate_id
join stock s on s.stock_id = f.stock_id
join origin o on o.origin_id = s.origin_id
group by o.origin_id, s.stock_id
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| ORIGIN_NAME | STOCK_TITLE | FINALSCORE |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| US          | P1          |         93 |
| CA          | P3          |         90 |
| MX          | Q4          |        100 |
| MX          | B3          |        100 |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Let me know if this did the trick.

Comment: `US P1` should have 100 because there is only case `{H}` and score is 100 therefore 100% * 100 = 100. `US P2` should have 100 because there is only case `{M}` which means `M`=100 and that `M` has the score of 100 in this case. Therefore 100%*100=100, `MX B3` has the case {HML} therefore `H`=70, `M`=20=, `L`=20. H has the score 90 because (90%*70) + (100%*20) + (100%*10) = 93. `MX Q4' has the case: {H,M,L} and all of gate (4) was found. So looking at `gate 4` which has the score (100% * H) + (50% * M) + (100% * L) which equals (70*100%) + (20*50%) + (10*100%) = 90

Comment: Given the fiddle you provided `P1` is the only stock present for `US`, so your data must be inaccurate in someway (or at least not match with the data in your question). See the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be72/3) you'provided

Comment: Mosty Mostacho - If you could please have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5752/1 for one more additional question. I promise this will be the last time I bother you for this :) Also, how do I grant you the reward from the bounty in answering this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would take your original query to get the second last table and change the `Select` by adding use `distinct` (found [here](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL)) and only select Origin, Stock and the calculation for the Score. For example if the score is an average of all of them it would be `AVG(Score)` where `Score` would be what you fetched in the original query. If you want to use only a small subset of the items that have the same Origin and Stock to calculate the Score I would use a subquery, with the where matching the Origin and Stick ids, in the select so you have:

```
Select Origin, 
       Stock, 
       (select calculation(Score) from tables where tables.stock_id = .... tables.origin_id = .....)
From....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didnt help me too much. I know I the gist of the pseudo code. I just cant figure how to create the actual sql

Comment: Maybe if you show us the sql to get your second last table we can narrow it down more to help you get the last table (the one you want).

Comment: Here ya go. I create the entire situation from what I've made it up to thus far here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be72/3

Comment: I am sorry but it looks like the SQL in your second column is fetching the results that you want (shown at the bottom). In which case why do you need us??

Comment: The second column isn't my concern. The query I supplied in sql fiddle is only to show where I've made it to. The problem is; How do I correctly compute the values from the premises above. Please look back at the revision I made. Thanks Kyra