# MySQL How do I insert across multiple tables correctly?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, insert

**If I have an input file like:**

```
US, P1, AgriZone, H, 1000, 1200, 1101, 1210
US, P2, ArgiZone, L, 120, 122, 345, 566
MX, Q4, FarmOne, H, 1120, 2200, 1111, 2345
```

**And I have the following tables**.

[Tables In SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b468b)

**My Problem:** How do I insert these records correctly into the db (considering one row falls into multiple tables)? How do I make sure that I only ever add unique table columns? Example `Agrizone` above only needs one entry in the table `Farm`? What is the typical approach here when inserting like this?

```
 try
      {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://" + this.getServer() + "/" + this.getDatabase(),
            user, password);

        Statement s1 = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        s1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO" ??);

        con.close();

      }
  Catch(Exception blah)
```

How do I manage this type of insert, making sure PKs and FKs are set up correctly?

Thanks greatly stackoverflow community!

Comment: did you try restricting the column to unique? and you can decide what to do in case of duplicate (update or ignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do implement constraints on your db tables

- For example FARM_TITLE in farm table should be UNIQUE (it not possibile to insert twice "Argizone")
- Use foreign key to link tables each other. This gurantees that you will be able to reconstruct a row of the file like: US, P1, AgriZone, H, 1000, 1200, 1101, 1210
  that has been "splitted" into multiple tables

-Use transactions: so you can do more insert statements on more tables. If an insert fails, rollback transaction so that you won't have a row of the file "partially" inserted on the db:

```
 try{
   con.setAutoCommit(false);
   //do the multiple queries

   con.commit()
}
catch(Exception e) {
   con.rollback();
}
```

A pseudo code with the sql insert for the row: US, P1, AgriZone, H, 1000, 1200, 1101, 1210

Is suppose US is an origin not yet in table origin so first insert the origin:

```
  //this is pseudo code that insert into db table and retreive the id inserted. ID shoul be primary key and autoincrement
 int origin_id = execute( INSERT INTO ORIGIN(ORIGIN_NAME) values ("US");

 //now we insert the P1 stock. Again STOCK_ID primary key auto inc
 int stock_id = execute( INSERT INTO STOCK(ORIGIN_ID, STOCK_TITLE) values (origin_id, "P1");

 //now fill table FARM
 int farm_id = execute (INSERT INTO FARM(STOCK_ID, FARM_TITLE, SIZE, FARM_COMPNENTS) values (stock_id,"Agrizone","H","100");

 //finally a cycle to insert in GATE suppose we have n entries in this case (1200, 1101, 1210). I image to have an array
 for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
     INSERT INTO GATE (FARM_ID, FARM_COMPONENTS) values (farm_id,value[i]);
```

Comment: Could you supply an example of how I would set up the insert on the first row of the input file (considering I would fix the database and create uniques)?

Comment: Sure but i need to fully understand the file row structure. For example: US, P1, AgriZone, H, 1000, 1200, 1101, 1210.  wich is the corrispondence between file field and db tables filed?

Comment: Ok each row on the file input is an entire represented Origin. The structure is ORIGIN, STOCK, FARM, SIZE, VALUE(1), VALUE(2).... VALUE(n). The tables can be found at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b468b . There can be up to n amount of values following. But the initial value(1) must be inserted into `Farm`, the rest of the values insert into table `GATE`

Comment: please refer to this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830062/mysql-how-do-i-create-this-subquery  for further explanation if needed. I drew diagram and all